# Is it possible to disambiguate conflicting type name in the using declaration?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, namespaces, collision

For example, both `System.Threading` and `System.Timers` has the class `Timer`. So if I would like to use `System.Timers.Timer` in a class that uses `System.Threading`, I have to use stuff like

```
System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

everytime I want to declare/initialize timers. Is there a way to tell the compiler that "whenever I say `Timer`, use `System.Timers.Timer` unless declared otherwise?" So that I can use simple

```
Timer t = new Timer();
```

in default cases to mean `System.Timers.Timer`, unless I specify explicitly

```
System.Threading.Timer t2 = new System.Threading.Timer();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create an alias for a type (or namespace). See [using Directive (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
using TimersTimer = System.Timers.Timer;

....

var myTimer = new TimersTimer();
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;
```

Now `Timer` refers to `System.Timers.Timer`, but everything else from either namespace is still available without a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

See [The using Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
using MyAlias = System.Timers.Timer;
var foo = new MyAlias();
```